# how can I set the startpoints of a gradient for a heatmap in googlemaps api v3 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

Google published an example of using a heatmap on googlemaps with their javascript api.  In this example, a gradient is set as a list of colors, presumably spaced linearly along the "heat" dimension (0 to 1).

From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap:

> ```
>  var gradient = [
>     'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
>     'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
>     'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
>     'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
>     'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
>     'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
>     'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
>     'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
>     'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
>     'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
>     'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
>     'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
>     'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
>     'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
>   ]
> ```

However, documents on android show that you can set the startpoints for the colors, so the points don't have to be spaced evenly.  From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/heatmap:

> ```
> // Create the gradient. int[] colors = {
>     Color.rgb(102, 225, 0), // green
>     Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)    // red };
>
> float[] startPoints = {
>     0.2f, 1f };
>
> Gradient gradient = new Gradient(colors, startPoints);
> ```

Is there anyway to do the same thing in javascript?  The effect I'm trying to get at is a heatmap where areas with no points are not covered at all (i.e transparent), and then set the first start point to a small value (say 0.01f), such that everything non-zero is covered by the color of my choice.